# Sanitize a hidden input value to always be an integer

Tags: php

I have a form with a hidden input that will always have an integer as a value automatically assigned in the code.

```
<form action="">
    <input name="pageNum" type="hidden" value="1">
</form>
```

How can I sanitize that value to always be the given integer? Even when someone alter the request like you would do with sql injection by adding a `'` after the value in the request. Because this was actually the case, somebody reported it as a sql injection security incident, after doing some testing. But the `1` just becomes `1\`'and breaks my code because `1\`'does not exist in an array where 1 does.

```
$pageNumber = $_POST['pageNum'];

if (!is_int($pageNumber)) {    // $pageNumber = "1\'" for this example
    // what can I do to make it 1 again?
}
```

Is there a way how I can accomplish this? Because this make that I get an internal server error further down in my code that makes people think it is a sql injection security vulnerability.

Comment: Did you give up on this???

Comment: No sorry, just busy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try intval($pageNumber)

Comment: I will go with this answer, this is what I did, it is enough. I've made another check somewhere else as well where this number has impact on an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pageNumber = "1\'";
preg_match("|\d+|", $pageNumber, $number);
var_dump($number);
```

This will just extract the numeric value in the string and put it inside $number.

Comment: What if the tampered value is `1asdf2`, which value would you use for the page number?

Comment: I am thinking that OP is getting it as "1\'" because of a sanitation routine he has, and the code above is only to extract in such cases. To answer your question, in above case, the value extracted would be 1.

Comment: @RobertCalove does have a point, I haven't even thought of more integers in the tampered value.

Comment: @Mentos93 Well the main idea is that if your data is hampered, you DO NOT try to get anything out of it and just go to default page. I was just showing you how to extract first numeric value from an alphanumeric string.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` values are always type string so `is_int()` won't work.  Just check `is_numeric()`:

```
if (!is_numeric($pageNumber)) {    // $pageNumber = "1\'" for this example
    $pageNumber = '1';
}
```

But since you know it should be an integer, this will get the proper number if it begins with the number or `0` if not:

```
$pageNumber = (int)$_POST['pageNum'];
```

You can't reliably parse a correct page number out of gibberish.  Also, if someone is trying to hack your server, you shouldn't care about giving them the correct page number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter_var function. For example:
filter_var($your_integer_value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options);

See this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score -1):

Parsing a number out of gibberish is a bit tricky because if there are other numbers in the text, you wouldn't know which number to parse out. (e.g. `1\2`, which # would you parse out? 1 or 2?)

The simplest solution would be to have the page default to an integer if you cannot parse it.

For example:

```
if (!is_int($pageNum))
    $pageNum = 1;
```

So if anyone is tampering with the POST variables, they cannot do anything tricky as it'll just default to 1.

Comment: `$_POST['pageNum']` will ALWAYS be type string so that won't work.